# how can I verify signed data coming for In-App Billing Android Market using Java (Servlet)

Tags: java, android, servlets, in-app-billing

While implementing the in-app billing for Android application, I came across a problem.

Let me explain the scenario first
We have a content server (data server) which has the list of products.
When user selects one from the list, he can be able to purchase it.
The purchase logic runs perfectly after I put my credit card detail using my test account.
In returns I am getting a signed data in Android device.

My Question is
1. Should I have to **verify the signed data in Android device** and then send some information or the data to Content server, which in return sends the product (I think this may not be good since there is no flow at server side to verify that the request is valid or not **or more precisely; that the signature data is generated by google market or not**)?
2. If I have to verify the data at server side, how can I do this? Should I have to send it to **Google market** (if yes, using which web service or API)?

Please help me to rectify this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your second question, hash (eg: MD5, SHA) the data and send the hash along with the data to the server. At the server, create a hash of the data and compare the hashes to verify them.

Comment: How can I make the hashes and compare the same at server side? kindly explore it further.

Comment: @Naved Hashing algorithms are deterministic. If you use the same hashing algorithm on the same content, you should end up with the same result regardless of the machine the data is at.

Comment: Can u give any example tutorial or share some sample program? I am so sorry, I could not understand it fully.

Comment: @yogiam, Thank you for the hint. My team has setup a server which generates a Hash string and sending it to the device. This string along with the nonce (which is also generated at server side) is used to start transaction at device side. The device is then sending that hash along with the signed data to the server and server is then verifying the request. This is working fine but I need to some more time to test it further. Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions you have to first create the in-app product using some sort of ID that I would then tie into a database you have on your server.  Using webservices then you query your db and see if the in-app id matches the ID in you product database.  Plus on top that you can use the Security [Nonces](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-signatures) and Signatures to verify.  Mostly you let Google handle the products and so you will hae to model the In-App products after your DB.  If you have too many products then you will have to handle it a standard way of creating mobile website ....

EDIT:
Well when you make the request, i.e. purchase, you first do the REQUEST_PURCHASE then you launch the PendingIntent that is returned by the Market.  Then you you handle the broadcasts intents that are sent by Market.  You specify four keys in the request then make a purchase request:

```
  Bundle request = makeRequestBundle("REQUEST_PURCHASE");
  request.putString(ITEM_ID, mProductId);

  // Note that the developer payload is optional.
  if (mDeveloperPayload != null) {
      request.putString(DEVELOPER_PAYLOAD, mDeveloperPayload);
      Bundle response = mService.sendBillingRequest(request);
      // Do something with this response.
  }
```

Then you have to use the PendingIntent to launch the checkoutUI (careful of the 1.6 to 2.0 differences where 1.6 requires this be launched separate from the Activity).  take a look at the PurchaseObserver.java in the Google examples.

"The Android Market application sends a RESPONSE_CODE broadcast intent, which provides error information about the request. If the request does not generate an error, the RESPONSE_CODE broadcast intent returns RESULT_OK, which indicates that the request was successfully sent. (To be clear, a RESULT_OK response does not indicate that the requested purchase was successful; it indicates that the request was sent successfully to Android Market.)"

Comment: That is what we are currently doing. But, my question is when we received nonces and signature from Market, then should I have to send it to content Server? If yes, how the content server will know that the signature and nonces came is not manually generated but generated by google market transaction?

Comment: Thank you for spending time to write this answer. However, I think my question may not clear its requirement. Ok, let me explain. I have handle all the things at Device side. After I received the signed data, I have to send it to the Content Server. My question is how the content server verifies that the signed data sent by the device is actually a transaction and not a fake one.

Comment: You'll have to have some sort of way to verify by sending a cert/key and then you program sends back a response key.  That really is the only way to verify that its not a fake request.

Comment: You mean you favor what Yogiam is saying?